# Is this a faulty parrallelism or is there an expression like this?

Tags: grammar

> A gardener can't just wish for a beautiful garden and one suddenly appears.

I happened to see this sentence on an article about the importance of making an effort, and i can see that the sentence means you can't get something only by wishing for it.

Is this sentence grammatically wrong? Or it's just a common expression ? Help!

Comment: Not every written text requires parallelism. Whether they do or don't depends on many factors.

Comment: The sentence is poorly written, but I'm ok with "A gardener can't just wish for a beautiful garden.and - poof!/voilà!/behold!/Tada!- one ... appears. The extra beat prevents the mind from trying to connect "and" with the second part of a compound verb. (The absence of a comma exacerbates this problem, but inserting a comma alone doesn't save the sentence from sounding awkward.)  To my ear, the urgency of the interjections ousts the mental template the audience would otherwise deploy on seeing "and" without a comma. Good style is often just a matter of invoking and filling such templates.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very interesting example of the flexibility of language, most notably of the English language.

> 'A gardener can't just wish for a beautiful garden and ...

What is expected is that we shall get a second verb dependent on *can’t*, such as

> ... expect one suddenly to appear.

Instead, all that gets stripped out and out of *no-grammatical-where* comes

> ... one suddenly appears.

So form follows meaning.  And we all understand.  The grammar is stretched but does not actually break.

Comment: Nice observation, but what is you answer to the question?